# Styling text on black background for easy readability in a content heavy website.

Tags: website-design, typography

I am currently working on a project where client wants the site to have black background. It is a community/ forum style website for long discussions.

I am having difficulty on styling text on black background for easy readability.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

One tool that I use commonly is [accessible-colors.com](http://accessible-colors.com/).

You can enter a foreground and background colour. It will tell you if they contrast well enough, and if not propose changes to foreground or background that would be more legible.

Enter #000000 for the black background. If you don't know what code the colour you want is [Google has a colour picker](https://www.google.com/search?q=color+picker) that gives you the hex value on the right. Just copy and paste that in to accessible-colors.com.

If you're not sure what colour to start with and you need inspiration, try using [colorsafe.co](http://colorsafe.co/). Again, enter #000000 (black) for the background and it will propose colours that can do the trick.

Ideally you want to pass what's called AA level guideline for [web accessibility](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-contrast.html). This will ensure that there's enough contrast between the text and background that users with low-vision problems can still read the website.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this table to obtain colors that have good readability on black background. 
Source : https://www.lifewire.com/contrasting-foreground-background-colors-4061363
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I need to keep text white on black background. But to me that's kind of tiring for reading large blocks on text. I am using 80-90% white text. Looking for some styling tips for font sizes, letter spacing and line heights to maximum readability.

Comment: Other than following obvious typography rules, keep in mind that around 80% of people prefer black text on white background:

No matter what you do dark background will tire the eyes.
You can use bigger fonts , boldness and also make sure it`s a sans serif. 
Use bigger spacing between white text. 
Try some grey shades as overlayed on black decreases high contrast and might improve readability.

Comment: It's probably the JPEG compression of the image, but I have a hard time reading the "Good" for Red on Black.